# Can we Set the coreplot piechart slice color with image

Tags: ipad, core-plot, pie-chart

I am using core plot in one of my ipad projects. Is it possible to set the color of all the  slices in a pie chart  with images.thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes. 
Implement the following method in your datasource and return a CPFill object that uses your image for the slice index requested.

```
-(CPFill *)sliceFillForPieChart:(CPPieChart *)pieChart recordIndex:(NSUInteger)index;
```

Comment: actually i need to set 3 different images to 3 slices of my pie chart is it possible to acheive  using this method..thx in adv